# Problem in MySQL View with LEFT JOIN... GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, view, mariadb

I have a query in MySQL like this:

```
SELECT
a.IdFactura,
(sum((a.Precio_sinIVA*a.Cantidad)-(a.Descuento/(1+a.IVA_Tipo)))) AS SUM,
(1-((b.Descuento_Cliente * 1.0)/100.00)) As DESCUENT,
(sum((a.Precio_sinIVA*a.Cantidad)-(a.Descuento/(1+a.IVA_Tipo)))) * (1-((b.Descuento_Cliente * 1.0)/100.00)) As Base_Imponible
FROM Lineas_Facturas a
LEFT JOIN Facturas b ON a.IdFactura = b.IdFactura
GROUP BY a.IdFactura
```

And the query returns, for example:

```
a.IdFactura   SUM    DESCUENT   Base_Imponible
655           29.75  0.9        26.77 (OK)
```

But when I include this query into a VIEW and I run it, the VIEW returns, for example:

```
a.IdFactura   SUM    DESCUENT   Base_Imponible
655           29.75  0.9        29.65 (WRONG)
```

I only want to multiply SUM * DESCUENT and in the query the result is OK but when I include it into a VIEW the result is different.

Where is the problem?. Could anybody help me, please?

UPDATED:

I've carefully reviewed the MySQL View and SQL Query and when I save the View the parentheses of the query change and some are deleted. The query saved in the view is this:

```
SELECT
a.IdFactura,
sum(a.Precio_sinIVA*a.Cantidad-a.Descuento/(1+a.IVA_Tipo)) AS SUM,
1-b.Descuento_Cliente * 1.0/100.00 As DESCUENT,
sum(a.Precio_sinIVA*a.Cantidad-a.Descuento/(1+a.IVA_Tipo)) * 1-b.Descuento_Cliente * 1.0/100.00 As Base_Imponible
FROM Lineas_Facturas a
LEFT JOIN Facturas b ON a.IdFactura = b.IdFactura
GROUP BY a.IdFactura
```

I have reviewed the query code and can do without all the parentesis in the DESCUENT field except 2 (parentheses at the beginning and end of the field):

```
(1-b.Descuento_Cliente * 1.0/100.00) As DESCUENT,
```

Without those two parentheses, all the calculation in '*Base_Imponible*' field is incorrect. Any ideas?.

Comment: did you check the DDL of the view to see it matches with this query?

Comment: Yes, it matches with the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the problem using CTE. The SQL View is:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT 
    Lineas_Facturas.IdFactura AS IdFactura,
    (sum(Precio_sinIVA*Cantidad-Descuento/(1+IVA_Tipo))) AS SUMA, 
    (1-Facturas.Descuento_Cliente * 1.0/100.00) AS DISCOUNT 
from Lineas_Facturas
LEft Join Facturas ON Lineas_Facturas.IdFactura = Facturas.IdFactura
GROUP BY Lineas_Facturas.IdFactura
)
SELECT IdFactura, (SUMA*DISCOUNT) AS Base_Imponible
FROM cte
```

Thank you very much.

Wardiam

Answer (score 0):

When you mix normal columns with aggregate functions you have to use `GROUP BY`. The `GROUP BY` should contains the normal columns from your `SELECT`.

You have columns `a.IdFactura` and `b.Descuento_Cliente` that are not inside an aggregate function, therefore you should include those in the `GROUP BY`. Older MySQL versions allowed this by default and you might see variable outcome as result (nothing to do with the parentheses).

To see if the query is otherwise correct, you could show some sample code and desired result.